# Setting JAVA_HOME to point to JDK properly?

Tags: android, bash, archlinux

Hello I have a noob question. I am trying to run Android Studio on my Arch Linux in the `/android-studio/bin` directory using: `./studio.sh`. However, I keep receiving this message: `JDK Required: 'tools.jar' seems to be not in Studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.`

So what I did was opened `~/.bashrc` and inserted this 
`JAVA_HOME='/java-7-openjdk/jre'
export JAVA_HOME
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH`

After rebooting, I still came across the following issue of the requirement. I am confused as to which part of the /path/to/java goes in `JAVA_HOME='?????'`

In the terminal, when I do `which java`, it shows `/usr/bin/java`
and when I do `whereis java`, it shows
`java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk/jre/bin/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz`

and as for `archlinux-java status` it also shows `java-7-openjdk/jre (default)` what is the exact path to put specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use java 8 for android studio

i think it will take only java 8

Comment: Thank you hemant! The change to 8, indeed worked. Also after that had to: `archlinux-java set java-8-openjdk/jre` and then it was good to go.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, using locate to find out where the tools.jar was located:

```
updatedb && locate tools.jar
```

Sample output

```
/opt/jdk1.7.0_55/db/lib/derbytools.jar
/opt/jdk1.7.0_55/lib/tools.jar
/opt/jdk1.7.0_55/lib/visualvm/visualvm/modules/com-sun-tools-visualvm-tools.jar
```

Then set JAVA_HOME,PATH on ~/.bashrc

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_55
export JRE_HOME=/opt/jdk1.7.0_55/jre
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JRE_HOME/jre/bin
```

after that relogin session or

```
source ~/.bashrc
```